# Wordpress Search Submit Not Working

Tags: php, wordpress, forms, search, submit

My search was working great before I changed the style of the form.

Now the search will not submit.

Here is my searchform.php:

```
<button type="button" class="close">×</button>
<form role="search" method="get" action="<?php echo home_url( '/' ); ?>">
   <input type="search" value="<?php get_search_query(); ?>" name="s" placeholder="search..." title="Search" />
   <button type="submit" id="searchsubmit" class="btn btn-default btn-search" value="Search"><i class="fa fa-search fa-4x"></i></button>
</form>
```

I am  developing on site http://www.2knowmusic.net. Search is on the top right.

Comment: Its working for me. I think its problem with popup overlay...

Answer (score 1):

Check out your footer or where the following is located. In the source code, you have:

```
//Do not include! This prevents the form from submitting for DEMO purposes only!
$('form').submit(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    return false;
})
```

This is preventing your form from being submitted which is why it's not doing anything.

Comment: Wow, I cant believe I didn't see that! Thank you